# can't access methods of loaded swf file

Tags: actionscript-3

I can't seem to access anything from a loaded swf file. I can, however access parent variables/methods from inside the loaded swf file.

```
var ldr:ProLoader;

function loadExternalSWF():void {
    ldr = new ProLoader();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest("introAS3.swf"));
    wrapperMC.addChild(ldr);
}

loadExternalSWF();

buttonNextMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonNextMC_Click);

function buttonNextMC_Click(event:MouseEvent):void {
    MovieClip(wrapperMC).ldr.gotoAndPlay(31);
}
```

This just gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

EDIT: wrapperMC is just an empty movie clip instance that I've created and positioned on the stage to load the external movie into.

Comment: OK, is the code you posted inside that empty clip? Is the path `wrapperMC.ldr` valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why should `wrapperMC` has a property with the name "ldr"? You could go with:

```
function loadExternalSWF():void {
    ldr = new ProLoader();
    ldr.load(new URLRequest("introAS3.swf"));
    ldr.name = "ldr";
    wrapperMC.addChild(ldr);
}

function buttonNextMC_Click(event:MouseEvent):void {
    MovieClip(MovieClip(wrapperMC).getChildByName("ldr")).gotoAndPlay(31);
}
```

On the other hand, it's unlikely that your loaded clip replaces your ProLoader object instead it's added it to it's own child collection. In this case, you have to get the loaders child to call `gotoAndPlay()`.

Without knowledge of of how ProLoader works I assume you have the following child structure

wrapperMC -> ldr -> introAS3

so you could go with:

```
MovieClip(DisplayObjectContainer(wrapperMC.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).gotoAndPlay(31);
```

But this is only a guess.

Comment: Thanks, the second method actually worked. It's just so weird that such a simple thing must be so complicated.

Comment: If you had reference directly to the Loaders content rather than reference to the wrapperMC then everything becomes a HELL of alot simpler. Its the way you have coded it that is requiring it to be complicated